# KnockoutJS Changes Model to Controller

Tags: knockout.js, jscript

I have a dropdownbox that is binded to videmodel with foreach

```
<td>
                        <input class='required' type="text" data-bind="value: muhasebekodu" id="muhasebekodu" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <select data-bind="options: gidertipleri, value: selectedOptionValue" onchange="SetCodeField(this.value);" id="muhcodes" name="muhcodess"></select></td>
```

And the model like this

```
    var self = null;
    var viewModel = null;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var giderlers = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnOutgoingTypes').value);
        var selectedGider = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnOutgoingTypesSelected').value;
        var odemetipleri = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnFirmPaymentTypes').value);
        var selectedOdemeTipi = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnFirmPaymentTypesSelected').value;
        var GiftModel = function (gifts) {
            self = this;
            self.gifts = ko.observableArray(gifts);

            self.addGift = function () {
                self.gifts.push({
                    muhasebekodu: ko.observable().extend({ notify: 'always' }),
                    gidertipleri: giderlers,
                    selectedOptionValue: ko.observable(selectedGider),
                    faturano: "",
                    matrah: "",
                    kdv: "",
                    geneltoplam: "",
                    kdvtipleri: ["0", "1", "8", "18"],
                    selectedOKDVptionValue: ko.observable("0"),
                    odemeseklitipleri: odemetipleri,
                    selectedOOSTptionValue: ko.observable(selectedOdemeTipi),
                    aciklama: "",
                });
            };

            self.removeGift = function (gift) {
                self.gifts.remove(gift);
            };

            self.save = function (form) {
                alert("Could now transmit to server: " + ko.utils.stringifyJson(self.gifts));
                // To actually transmit to server as a regular form post, write this: ko.utils.postJson($("form")[0], self.gifts);
            };
        };


        viewModel = new GiftModel([
            { muhasebekodu: ko.observable().extend({ notify: 'always' }), gidertipleri: giderlers, selectedOptionValue: ko.observable(selectedGider), faturano: "", matrah: "", kdv: "", geneltoplam: "", kdvtipleri: ["0", "1", "8", "18"], selectedOKDVptionValue: ko.observable("0"), odemeseklitipleri: odemetipleri, selectedOOSTptionValue: ko.observable(selectedOdemeTipi), aciklama: "" },
        ]);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

        // Activate jQuery Validation
        //$("form").validate({ submitHandler: viewModel.save });


        $(".faturanoinp").bind('keyup', function (e) {
            $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
        });

    });
```

I want to set my muhasebekodu input when user changed dropdown control on same screen, i have write below jscript.  it has been changed the new value in model but it is not apearing on control

```
    function SetCodeField(e) {
        var mcode = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnmuhasebekodlari').value;
        var mcodes = mcode.split(",");
        for (i = 0; i < mcodes.length; i++) {
            var namevalues = mcodes[i].split(":");
            var name = namevalues[0];
            var value = namevalues[1];
            if (e == name) {
                self.gifts()[self.gifts.length].muhasebekodu.value = value;
                self.gifts()[self.gifts.length].muhasebekodu.extend({ notify: 'always' });
            }
        }
    }
```

i have 2 control one of them changed i want to see on another control always binded to the viewmodel. 
self.gifts.XXX = 'new value'; i want to see this on binded control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In knockout you set the value of an observable like this:

```
self.gifts()[self.gifts.length].muhasebekodu(value);
```

Comment: Thank you Tom self.gifts()[self.gifts().length-1].muhasebekodu(value);